# WebApp manifest.json for adaptive icons

Tags: android, html, web-applications, android-8.0-oreo

My application is a **web app** that can be added to the home screen (by using Google Chrome, for instance).

However, I would like to use **Adaptive Icons**, which Android Oreo introduced. Currently, my icon is forced into a circle by the Google Pixel Launcher:

[image]

**Q:** Is there a way to use adaptive icons, or at least circular icons in web apps?

---

**index.html**

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "short_name": "My app",
    "name": "My app",
    "icons":
    [
        {
            "src": "images/favicon-192px.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "192x192"
        }
    ],
    "display": "standalone",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
    "theme_color": "#000000"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be only on Googke Pixel Launcher? Did you try using other Launcher?

Icon must be transparent to be Adaptive Icon.

Can you send the current Icon that you are using?

Regards,
Developer From jokela

Comment: I'm basically using a gray square. After trying a gray circle, I realized there is some "automagical" algorithm, deciding what to do with that icon. This may solve my problem, but for future readers and myself it would still be interesting what needs to be done to create the desired result, rather than trial-and-error, which I'm currently doing.